# Not updating (loading) textures each frame in animation render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing

I am rendering animation in Cycles Renderer and I noticed that for each image render, renderer loads all textures.

Is there a way to tell renderer to use same textures for every frame (whole animation) and not to load them every time new image is being rendered?

Considering I am using over 100MB of textures it would make rendering notably faster.

(PS. I am rendering on GPU)

**Edit:**

<s>Here is my simplified blend file https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5sbs56wd8pq3xh/textureLoading.blend?dl=0. It is on Dropbox because Blend-Exchange has 30MB limit.</s> Dead link

**Edit 2:**

When rendering on CPU, loading is barely noticable but on GPU (I have GeForce GTX 760) it takes around one second and you can see rendering "pauses" between each frame.

Comment: I think your question will remain unclear without any insight to your texture settings...

Comment: I wish there would be a way to make cycles not reload the texture on every render/frame like the Blender internal does. Thought "Persistent Images" would do the trick, but no. All I can find are simular situations with workarounds like using low res images or bitmaps like here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/why-does-blender-use-so-much-memory-for-large-textures

Comment: Thank you for "Persistent Images" it actually took one second off each frame rendering time. Plus it led me to this site http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/. Beside the article itself a lot of comments are helpful too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activating "Persistent Images" in Render -> Performance helped. Plus activating some other options in Performace section sped up rendering too. This article http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles could be useful for some. Beside the article itself a lot of comments are helpful too.

Comment: Enabling persistent images eliminated a 15 second lag between each frame - a big deal when it only took 8 seconds to actually render a frame. My image was a 54MB navigation chart which remained static anyway.

Comment: Enabling persistent images improved my render time from 40 to 4 seconds per frame. Was using a 900MB PNG as asteroid texture.

Comment: Still a perfect solution in current Blender version 2.91.2, this checkbox cut my animation render time in half. (GPU rendering on GeForce 1070 GTX)