# Cycles GPU rendering CUDA error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

[image]I have problems rendering with Blender 2.79 on my GeForce GTX 760 which has 2048 MB. The untit runs out of memory when about only 220 MB are filled with texture images.

Why is this so and how can it be avoided?

The attached image from a Blender command line protocoll gives details.

Comment: When you run out of memory it means exactly that: your scene is larger than what the GPU can handle. You have large textures (one is an HDR at 2K, other is an image at 4K and there is yet another at 6k. All of that on top of whatever other complexity your scene might have (you didn't describe it). To understand how Blender uses RAM fo read images please read: [Why does Blender use so much memory for large textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/why-does-blender-use-so-much-memory-for-large-textures/27696#27696)

Comment: If the GPU is the only graphics card on the computer and is connected to the monitor (or monitors) then there is even less vRAM available. Try to simplify the scene or render it in parts: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing