# Advice about importing huge .gltf files w/ and w/o textures

Tags: import, gltf

I would like to import a model made up of thousands of files and many millions of vertices. I have ran my PC for around 30 hours but decided to stop the process and rethink my import workflow. The gltf files are about 2GB and another 4GB for png textures. My first question is, does importing textures affect import speed? If it does, can I import the mesh first and then import the corresponding textures after? Is there a limit of how many vartices I can have at the same time in the scene?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/why-does-blender-use-so-much-memory-for-large-textures — the 4GB of PNGs will often take _far more_ than 4GB in memory, so I suspect you're throwing more at Blender that your PC can handle here. Tools like gltfpack and RapidCompact can optimize the glTF file and might help to make this more manageable.

Comment: Hey @Andrey, could you solve your problem? I also run into simiar issue that I can't import a big glTF file. Blender just freezes and nothing happens for hours.

Comment: @filibis Sorry for the late reply. Yes, the issue was that blender stores files in ram and it simply ran out of memory so import went from 0.03s per file to over 10s per file. My workaround was running a script to import files in order and stopping it when it got too slow. (buying more ram also helped greatly)